# passing argument to an ajax post request returns an error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an applicatiuon MVC wirtten in c#.
I want to make ajax post request to my controller method:

```
locationId = "2087";
jQuery.ajax({
    url: rootUrl + "SpaEmployeeAdmin/GetCurrentLocationDateTime",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "locationId=" + locationId,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        //data.someObject
    }
});
```

My  signature of a method looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetCurrentLocationDateTime(int? locationId = null)
{}
```

but however, I'm receiving an error exception of this ajax call:

```
"System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: locationId.
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
   at System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetDeserializedObject(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.ValueProviderFactory_GetValueProvider.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.CastleInvocationToAlternateMethodContextAdapter.Proceed()
   at Glimpse.Core.Extensions.AlternateMethodContextExtensions.TryProceedWithTimer(IAlternateMethodContext context, TimerResult& timerResult)
   at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateMethod.NewImplementation(IAlternateMethodContext context)
   at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateTypeToCastleInterceptorAdapter.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.ValueProviderFactoryProxy.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)"
```

how to write properly thisparameter? without parameter and removing the input argument from my method, ajax call works.

Answer (score 0):

It's having trouble parsing your data so you will need to serialize it as json before posting. It would help to use a LocationRequest model as well.

Try this:

```
locationId = 2087;
jQuery.ajax({
    url: rootUrl + "SpaEmployeeAdmin/GetCurrentLocationDateTime",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({locationId}), //serialize json
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        //data.someObject
    }
});
```

```
public class LocationRequest
{
  public int LocationId { get; set; }
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetCurrentLocationDateTime(LocationRequest request)
{
  //request.LocationId
}
```

Comment: thanks, is it possible not having LocationRequest, just one param `int? locationId` ?

Comment: in that case you could pass locationId as part of the URL. [HttpPost("GetCurrentLocationDateTime/{locationId}")] and don't need to post a body. Your url on the client side ajax request would be "SpaEmployeeAdmin/GetCurrentLocationDateTime/" + locationId.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` parameter for the `ajax` call should be formatted as a JSON object like the following:

```
locationId = "2087";
jQuery.ajax({
    url: rootUrl + "SpaEmployeeAdmin/GetCurrentLocationDateTime",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { locationId: locationId },
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        //data.someObject
    }
});
```

By convention, the server side C# expects the body of the request to be JSON, with the method parameter names defined as properties on the JSON object.